# Retrieve Woocommerce Custom Fields

Tags: woocommerce

Woocommerce has change the file structure sine version 2 onwards. Now the list of custom fields are placed inside WC_Admin_Profile class. I want to access these custom fields within another plugin.

We can inlcude the WC_Admin_Profile class as it duplicates the fields on admin section. Is there a way to get custom fields or call WC_Admin_Profile functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply call get_user_meta() for custom user fields or get_post_meta() for custom order fields (I am not sure what exactly you are referring to)?